# Font face in sublime text 3 using Elementary OS

Tags: ubuntu, font-face, sublimetext3, italic

I have a problem. Earlier I used Ubuntu, but now I've installed an Elementary OS to my notebook and then installed a sublime text 3. But I don't like a font_face in new OS. It is not so good, like it was in Ubuntu, e.g. Zero sign is not striped. And also keywords is not italic like. Can you help me to fix it?

Comment: Your links from Dropbox are broken `404
We can’t find what you’re looking for.`

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I've removed them

Comment: For installing font in ubuntu type command ``sudo apt install fonts-firacode``

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Open `Preferences > Settings - User` and add the following:

`"font_face": "Ubuntu Mono",
 "font_size": 10,
 "font_options": [],`

If this doesn't work, **try changing the font**. There are plenty of choices at [Google Fonts](http://www.google.com/fonts). You just need to add the desired fonts to your collection, click the download icon in the top right, and install the .ttf's on your system, which should be as easy as opening the files and clicking on install.

Monospace is the default font in most Linux systems, but you can change it to whatever you like. However, I personally prefer the "Ubuntu Mono" font that is installed by default.

the font_option array should be blank. Sublime Text lets you add options like "no_bold", "no_italic", "no_antialias", etc...

Lastly, make sure you are editing the Settings - User page and not the Settings - Default page.

Comment: I did so, but nothing changed.

Comment: May be I should use another font. When I type in sublime console view.settings.get('font_face') in Windows. I received: 'Consolas'. Here -- 'Monospase'. But when i use "font_face": "Consolas" -- always crashes

Comment: Try replacing it to "font_face": "Ubuntu Mono", do the italics work?

Comment: @Mike_Device I've added to my answer. Let me know if this works.

Comment: Thank you very much. I've downloaded Ubuntu Mono font and installed it.  It's working. This font is a bit unusual, but it's not a problem, because now I can install another. Thank you again :)

Comment: I'm happy its fixed!Ubuntu Mono is a bit strange at first, but it's become one of my favorite fonts. You can explore lots of other ones on the Google fonts page I linked to.

Answer (score 2):

From [here](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/font.html), changing the font can be done via adding these lines to **Preferences/Settings - User**:

```
"font_face": "Courier New",
"font_size": 10
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's not what I want. I always used native font_face, but in Windows, Ubuntu, XUbuntu it was better, because word like a "function", "var" etc was is italic. So I want to fix it, but save native font

Comment: [picture](https://www.dropbox.com/s/dbnf1bwlsvfx3je/%D0%A1%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BA%20%D1%8D%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%BE%D1%82%202014-11-30%2018%3A33%3A44.png?dl=0) how it was (and I want).

[picture](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jw6kc08jpfgh7yb/%D0%A1%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BA%20%D1%8D%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%BE%D1%82%202014-11-30%2018%3A31%3A41.png?dl=0) how it's now